# How can I transform my logistic regression with a binary categorical predictor?

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model

I'm carrying out a logistic regression with a binary categorical predictor. Specifically, the predictor is two alleles of a genetic variant. The software that I'm using to carry out my logistic regression provides me with four values:

- The odds ratio
- The standard error of log(OR)
- The bottom and top of confidence the intervals (CI=0.95).

However, this software formats the logistic regression differently depending on the relative frequencies of the predictors; it always looks at the probability the **minor allele frequency** affects the phenotype.

In other words, for the binary predictor values **T** and **A**, if there are less values for T I will get the odds ratio, standard error and confidence intervals for T's effect, and vice versa for A.

In instances where there are less values for A, how can I transform the values the software generates so that it represents the probability T is affecting the phenotype?

(I believe that what I'm asking is the logistic regression equivalent of multiplying a standard linear regression by -1 in order to flip it.)

Comment: What software are you using? // A hack around this might be to put in some conditional logic (`if/else`) about the relative frequency and output the desired probability.

Comment: I'm using PLINK to perform GWAS on binary traits - I don't think it's possible to provide it with that logic unfortunately as it's essentially just a CLI that takes arguments.

Comment: Well, my question just pertains to logistic regression which is applicable here. I suppose I could remove the context but I originally added it because it might aid understanding.

Comment: Do you hava just 2 binary variables, one the respomse and the other a sole predictor ?

Comment: Yes: the predictor is a binary variable of either A or T, and the response is a binary variable of 'disease positive' or 'disease negative'.

Comment: So, it sounds like you have a 2x2 contingency table. In that case you can calculate the odds ratio, SE and CI directly. If the counts are $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ (left to right, top to bottom) then the OR is just $ad/bc$. The standard error of the odds ratio can be estimated as $\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}}$ and using  the normal approximation for the log odds ratio and then translating back, the CI bounds are $\exp\{\ln(OR) \pm 1.96 \times SE \}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have everything I said I need in the question now but have just realised I also have to adjust the wald Z score to apply to the other predictor - do you know how this would be done?

Comment: Also, out of interest (and because it might be helpful to others), I'd still appreciate my main question answered if anybody knows it (transforming ORs etc).